# How to find the odds ratios for a logistic model?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I have a standard logistic regression model in R

`reg <- glm(formula = y ~ x, family = "binomial"(link='logit'))`

I am trying to find the odds ratios for my model in R. Is there a function or some other way to do this?

Comment: The title of this question has to do with reporting. The body of this question seems to be about whether there's a good function or way to calculate odds ratios of a model.

Comment: @Galen sorry for the confusion... the title has been updated

Comment: This post seems useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/logistic-regression-in-r-odds-ratio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The log odds ratio can be found by

```
reg$coefficients
```

... and the odds ratio would be

```
exp(reg$coefficients)
```

... the log of 2.5% and 97.5% levels of the confidence intervals would be

```
confint.default(reg)
```

... following that the 2.5% and 97.% levels of the confidence intervals would be

```
exp(confint.default(reg))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a good way to find the odds ratios

`exp(coef(reg))`